# Qt QGuiApplication or QApplication causes "No NSMainNibFile .." error

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, qt, osx-yosemite

I am building an Application Extension for OSX 10.10 using Qt libraries.

Ultimately, I need to instantiate `QApplication` to create `QWidget`-derived classes. The software behaves as expected, as long as it's built with:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    NSLog(CFSTR("Invoking Main"));
    __asm__ ("call _NSExtensionMain");
}
```

Building it with

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication a(argc, argv);
    NSLog(CFSTR("Invoking Main"));
    __asm__ ("call _NSExtensionMain");
}
```

Causes the following error on runtime:

```
24/10/2014 14:40:08.091 My_ShellExt[32427]: Invoking Main  
24/10/2014 14:40:08.092 My_ShellExt[32427]: No NSMainNibFile or NSMainStoryboardFile specified in info dictionary, exiting
24/10/2014 14:40:08.095 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (me.qdot.My_Daemon.My_ShellExt[32427]) Service exited with abnormal code: 1
```

Comment: Well, do you have a `NSMainNibFile` or `NSMainStoryboardFile` in your info dictionary?

Comment: Well, I don't - but neither does a typical QWidget-Based Qt/OSX Application - since Qt manages it's own UI programmatically.